# System file copying dialog box

Tags: windows, api, windows-7, file-copying

Sometimes, setup programs shows the Windows file copy dialog, like this one:

[image]

This often appears during driver-level application installation, either on Windows XP or Windows 7.

Which API can perform that?

**EDIT**

Actually, there is no Cancel button at all on the real dialog box.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows API is called SHFileOperation.
Its signature in C# language is

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll",CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern int SHFileOperation([In] ref SHFILEOPSTRUCT lpFileOp);
```

If you like an example you could look [at this page](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.SHFileOperation) on PInvoke
This instead is the [link to the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation on SHFileOperation

Answer (score 1):

The Windows API SHFileOperation is declared as follows:

[DllImport("shell32.dll",CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern int SHFileOperation(ref SHFILEOPSTRUCT lpFileOp);

Specifying [In] for ref SHFILEOPSTRUCT lpFileOp prevents receiving the pointer to any remapped files in ref SHFILEOPSTRUCT.hNameMappings when FOF_WANTMAPPINGHANDLE flag is set.